# Does Android App have a chance to know when it is about to be killed by System when memory is low?

Tags: android

I do some initialization work(such as open DB or init disc cache for image) at Application.onCreate or MainActivity.onCreate, but there is no chance for us to do uninitlization work(such as close DB or flush/close/uninit disc cache for image) when App is about to be killed by system.

We all know Application.onDestroy is only invoked on emulator......

Anybody can do me a fovour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `onLowMemory` method. As defined in the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29):

> This is called when the overall system is running low on memory, and
>   actively running processes should trim their memory usage. While the
>   exact point at which this will be called is not defined, generally it
>   will happen when all background process have been killed. That is,
>   before reaching the point of killing processes hosting service and
>   foreground UI that we would like to avoid killing.
>
> You should implement this method to release any caches or other
>   unnecessary resources you may be holding on to. The system will
>   perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.

Comment: onLowMemory will never be called when my App is killed by system when memory is low.

Comment: if your app is killed then you don't need to _"close DB or flush/close/uninit disc cache for image"_